# If I parallel two crystal filters together, will that double the bandwidth?

Tags: electronics, transceiver, filter, bandwidth

Will the bandwidth be doubled ?
And will the impedance be halved ?

Comment: no. But that single word might not be the answer you're looking for. Can you explain why you think that would be the case? Why do you care?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out, the short answer is no. The Q value for the series resonance of a crystal can be calculated from $Q = \frac{2\pi f_s L_m}{r_m}$. Q value is of course related to the bandwidth: $Q = \frac{f_s}{BW}$. If you take the equivalent circuit for a crystal, add another similar next to it, and then simplify the circuit as far as you can, you can see that both $L_m$ and $r_s$ are halved and the $Q$ is not affected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer about bandwidth is "not doubled, but not the same".

As demonstrated in a previous answer, Q of two identical crystals in parallel remains the same.

But BW of the  filter is determined not only by crystals' Q (unloaded Q) but also by generator and load impedances.

If those are << than Rm (xtal series R at series resonance) then BW with 2 xtals is the same.

But if >> then it tends to 2x because they are lowering the "loaded Q" of the filter.

What are your design needs?